# Audio distoreted after exporting on Premiere Pro

Tags: audio, export, audio-quality

I just finished my video on premiere pro. The sound is nice when I'm listening to my premiere pro's video; however, my audio is distorted once I exported. I already used premiere pro before for a similar project and never had any problem. I did the last update; maybe it is a problem?

The only thing I did now is to slow down some videos.

The effect I choose for the audio are:

DeNoise
Dynamic Processing
Parametric equalizer
Multiband compressor

Thank you in advance for all help you can provide.
Have a great evening,
Pauline.

Comment: This is difficult to solve without having access to your project and audio files. Try a new project where you import the same audio and make a simple sequence where you don't apply any effects. Then export it (you could export only audio for faster results). Does the problem still exist? If yes, it could be some issue of whatever video player you use or your system. If no, then it might be related to the audio effects you use in the original project, although that wouldn't explain why it can only be heard after export. If the problem presists, it might be best to chat with Adobe about this.

Comment: Alternatively share the project and audio files with us (video can be omitted) and tell us which audio format you've used so far for export.